# How to use Mouse's Right Click Manually on keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, mouse

I'm using MacBook Pro. My Apple mouse that I only got last year when I right click on the mouse, nothing happens. I'm supposed to get a delete message so I can "move to trash" or "remove reference" my files. Since my right click on mouse isn't working. How do I get the delete followed by "move to trash" or "remove reference" to appear by clicking what on keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>option</kbd> click.

You can set your mouse to use right click in the **System Preferences**. Go to the  logo at the top left of your screen to get there. Or click the icon on your dock.